# Jump to search result shortcut in XCode

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

After I've searched on something I want a keyboard shortcut to focus on the search results so I can step through them.

I've looked in XCode's key bindings with no luck.

[image]

Comment: Did you find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ctrl+cmd+G**

Keybinding is called "Find next in Workspace"

Answer (score 0):

Use `Show Find Navigator` shortcut (by default it's **Cmd+3**)

[Preferences page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oe7Ae.png)

Comment: He doesn't want to show the panel, but to jump into the search results to start iterating